# Trouble Connecting to my Mongo Server Running on AWS. Node process doesn't start, but Mongod log looks fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I start my mongod server, it runs perfectly fine. I opened up all connections to try and fix this issue, so don't mind the warning. When I try to run my node process, which connects to my server through its public IP (I have that set so I can connect to my database from home too). However, my node process never actually starts, but the mongo server shows a

```
[conn1] received client metadata from Censored IP: 46534 conn1: {
    driver: {
        name: "nodejs",
        version: "3.1.10"
    },
    os: {
        type: "Linux",
        name: "linux",
        architecture: "x64",
        version: "4.15.0-1031-aws"
    },
    platform: "Node.js v11.4.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.9"
}
```

My mongo config is:

```
# for documentation of all options, see: #http: //docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    #Where and how to store data.
storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib / mongodb
journal:
    enabled: true# engine: #mmapv1: #wiredTiger:

    #where to write logging data.
systemLog:
    destination: file
logAppend: true
path: /var/log / mongodb / mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
    port: 27017
bindIp: ::, 0.0 .0 .0# bindIpAll: true# how the process runs
processManagement:
    timeZoneInfo: /usr/share / zoneinfo

# security: #authorization: enabled# operationProfiling:

    #replication:

    #sharding:

    ##Enterprise - Only Options:

    #auditLog:

    #snmp:
```

I use mongoose to connect, and only have run into this issue once before, and fixed it temporarily, but not sure why my node process won't connect to the mongod server and start up normally.
Mongod Log:

```
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.390 + 0000 I STORAGE[initandlisten] WiredTiger message[1547051759: 390412][3431: 0x7f79c7a83a40], txn - recover: Recovering log 25 through 26
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.442 + 0000 I STORAGE[initandlisten] WiredTiger message[1547051759: 442748][3431: 0x7f79c7a83a40], txn - recover: Recovering log 26 through 26
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.486 + 0000 I STORAGE[initandlisten] WiredTiger message[1547051759: 486445][3431: 0x7f79c7a83a40], txn - recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.530 + 0000 I RECOVERY[initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp.Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.547 + 0000 I CONTROL[initandlisten]
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.547 + 0000 I CONTROL[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled
for the database.
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.547 + 0000 I CONTROL[initandlisten] ** Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.547 + 0000 I CONTROL[initandlisten]
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.584 + 0000 I FTDC[initandlisten] Initializing full - time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 35: 59.585 + 0000 I NETWORK[initandlisten] waiting
for connections on port 27017
2019 - 01 - 09 T16: 36: 10.088 + 0000 I NETWORK[listener] connection accepted from Censored IP: 46534 #1 (1 connection now open)
2019-01-09T16:36:10.095+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from Censored IP:46534 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.10" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.15.0-1031-aws" }, platform: "Node.js v11.4.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.9" }
```

If anyone knows what's wrong, please let me know!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

My .env is:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://censoredip:27017/theseus
```

Comment: Can you please show the code to connect mongodb from nodejs code? That might point to something..

Comment: Should the bind ip not be 0.0.0.0 to let it be connected from all IPs, instead of spaces as in '0.0 .0 .0'

Comment: I read on the docs page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/
to get it to bind to all ipv4 and ipv6 just in case

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue! I experimented around and found it had nothing to do with Mongo. I actually didn't execute anything and a function must have disappeared or been accidentally deleted. Sorry for the trouble and thanks Ravi!